# resizeColumnToContents() not working Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

I have this treeView widget with the following building function:

```
void berichtenhistorie::DirectoryDisplay()
{
    QFileSystemModel *dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    dirModel->setRootPath("path");
    dirModel->setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs);
    ui->treeView->setModel(dirModel);
    ui->treeView->setRootIndex(dirModel->index("path"));
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
    ui->treeView->hideColumn(2);
    ui->treeView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    ui->treeView->sortByColumn(3);
    ui->treeView->resizeColumnToContents(0);
    ui->treeView->resizeColumnToContents(3);
}
```

But the `ui->treeView->resizeColumntoContents(#);`
I don't get any error's, but it won't resize it. It looks like this:
[image: This is how it looks like now]

But this is how it supposed to look like
[image: This is how it supposed to look]

How do I  make this working properly?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to call `ui->treeView->resizeColumnToContents(0);` The first column has index 0.

Comment: Ah yea you are right, but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: I also tried to only resize column 0 and remove resize colum 3 but that doesnt work either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I worked on a project that involves `QTableWidget` and I've used the header of the tablewidget to set the resize mode, looking the [documentation of QTreeView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtreeview.html#header) I can see that have a header too, then this code should works for you:

EDIT:

If you are using Qt4:

```
ui->treeView->header()->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->treeView->header()->setResizeMode(3, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Then if you are using Qt5:

```
ui->treeView->header()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->treeView->header()->setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
```

Comment: I get an error: `error: C2039: 'setResizeMode' : is not a member of 'QHeaderView'`

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using? (4.8.5, 5.1.1 etc)

Comment: Note that for a `QTableView` the methods to access the headers are (in Qt 5):
`QTableView::horizontalHeader()` and
`QTableView::verticalHeader()`. `QListView` does not display headers.

Comment: Your solution does not include information of what to do if `SectionResizeMode` is `Interactive`. You simply disallow user to resize columns at all.

Comment: @YevheniiMamontov: My solution provides automatic resize of the columns based on it's contents and on the rules for resizing each column. This makes the column not re sizable by the user as you said, however i think it's a characteristic, not a defect of my code.

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem in my qt5 project, the resizeColumnToContents(0) will not work as expected at the 1st time into a folder, but it will work well at the 2nd time into the same folder. then I find the page and use the above answer to use

```
   `ui->treeView->header()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);`
```

at beginning, and comment all resizeColumnToContents(0) in my code, then it work well always.